# JNA problem with char** (in dll)

Tags: java, dll, pointers, char, jna

ok it is 'easy' to make jna wrapper solution for mapping exported functions within dll using jna:

```
long f1(int x), just int
long f2(char* y), just char[]
```

but how to deal with `long f3(char** z)` ?

I need `f3`'s result(long) as well as `z` value on java side.

Please don't say cpp code should be rewritten to avoid this:-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a "pointer to a character pointer" (similar to a BSTR). You may have to [derive your own class from com.sun.jna.PointerType](http://markmail.org/message/ypuginjtwdvqc6do#query:java%20JNA%20bstr+page:1+mid:mpoiqq36yxdnbgy2+state:results)